# Chat with Django-chant

Tags: python, django, websocket, chat, tornado

Hi guys I wonder If some of you have already created a chat app with the library django-chant:

https://github.com/night-crawler/django-chant

I find this library very interesting, but I couldn't install it

when I start the project with the command:

```
./manage.py startchant 8877
```

and I go to the localhost in the port indicated I get:

```
Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket"
```

Answer (score 0):

Necroanswering: `startchant` is a shell command that starts tornado server. You have also to start `./manage.py runserver` to use chat.